# Generate information based on content in RoR, any ideas on that?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I have many products, each product belong to one category. 
How can I generate each category in hyper text, and when I click on the category hyper text, I can get all the products which is belongs to this category. And ideas on that?

Answer (score 0):

In your controller:

```
@category = Category.find(params[:id]) 
@products = @category.products
```

and then in view:

```
<% @products.each do |p| %>
  <p><%= p.name %></p>
<% end %>
```